# Disable Windows service at application launch

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vlc

Because of [VLC conflict](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=58516) I have to turn off Windows Advanced Text Services at my application launch. Is there any special API for that? Will it work for user with default rights?

Comment: It is not really polite to disable services that aren't your own; maybe the user needs this service running.  You should at least notify the user somewhere (help screen, readme, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ServiceController _ServiceController = new ServiceController([NameService]);
if (!_ServiceController.ServiceHandle.IsInvalid) 
{
     _ServiceController.Stop();
     _ServiceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(uConstante.CtTempoEsperaRespostaServico));
}
```

Comment: For correct code: `_ServiceController.ServiceHandle != null` is replaced to `!_ServiceController.ServiceHandle.IsInvalid && _ServiceController.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped`

Answer (score 32):

The question is titled "Disable Windows service..." but the answers all tell how to stop a service.

Most of what you will find on Google is that you can update the registry to disable a service using something like this:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\[YourServiceName]", true);
key.SetValue("Start", 4);
```

I haven't tried that method but it appears as though it will work. I also came up with a different method that uses sc.exe to disable the service:

```
Process sc = Process.Start("sc.exe", "config [YourServiceName] start= disabled");
```

Comment: +1 This is the only answer that actually answers the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI for that.

Look here, for example: http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=114

Comment: This article should be copy/pasted into this answer.  That page no longer exists unfortunately and the Wayback machine is down currently for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ServiceController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class for this. There are code samples in the linked documentation page.

Comment: `ServiceController` can report whether or not the service is disabled, but the properties are read-only and do not actually allow disabling of any service.

Answer (score 0):

just execute "net stop service-name" to stop a service or "net start service-name" to start a service.
type "net start" in the console (cmd.exe) in order to list all services.

You need admin privileges in order to enable/disable services.