# How to change the startup type of Windows service to Disabled programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, windows, service, servicecontroller

Hi I'm trying to change the startup type of a existing Windows service. Say "Spooler" ( Print Spooler). I'm using `ServiceController`

```
   var service = new ServiceController("Spooler");
                    service.Start();
                    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, 600);
```

Though I'm able to start/stop services I'm not able to figure out how can I  change the startup type itself? ( eg: Disabled/Automatic/Manual ) [image]

When I peek definition of `ServiceController` I can see `ServiceStartMode`  being defined. Could someone help me how can I set this option?. My need is to disable a Windows service programmatically using  ServiceControl class or any other feasible way..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop Windows service programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317378/how-to-stop-windows-service-programmatically)

Comment: You may want to look at the answers at [Disable Windows service at application launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052649/disable-windows-service-at-application-launch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a [sc command tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/controlling-a-service-using-sc):

Example for changing the startup type to disabled:

```
sc config "MySql" start=disabled
```

Note you need to have the administrator privileges to run this command successfully.

Wrapping with C# code:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{               
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    FileName = "CMD.EXE",
    Arguments = string.Format("/C sc {0} {1} {2}", "config", "MySql", "start=disabled"),
};

using (var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo})
{
    if (!process.Start())
    {
        return;
    }

    process.WaitForExit();

    Console.WriteLine($"Exit code is {process.ExitCode}");
}
```

**Update:**
Use `process.Exit` code to check if process the operation succeeded or not.
0 `ExitCode` is success.

Note: In case you are running the process/Visual Studio without the Admin privileges, the `ExitCode` will be 5 (access deined).

Comment: Thanks for this. In fact I had tried this already. The problem I see here is, after process.Start(), when I inspect process object, I saw InvalidOperationException. So I couldn't rely on "HasExited" property of Process , to determine if the operation was successful or not